# How to optimize the javascript code

Tags: javascript

I am getting an error "Don't make function inside a loop".

My code is

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('contentFrame');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var buttons =innerDoc.getElementsByClassName('RIC_Metrics');
var WTz_linkric_rp;
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var DCSuri = "/edge/web/public/viewGroupBenefits/RIC";

    if(this.id === "Retirement Income Center")
        WTz_linkric_rp = "TopNav_Retirement Income Centre";
    else(this.id === "Retirement Income Education")
        WTz_linkric_rp = "TopNav_Retirement Income Education";


    var grpId = Bootstrapper.data.extract('groupNumberForPreSignIn', 'cookie');
    if (typeof window.dcsMultiTrack == "function") window.dcsMultiTrack("DCS.dcsuri", DCSuri, "WT.z_linkric_rp_test", WTz_linkric_rp,"WT.z_cookieric_rp_test", grpId);
    });
}'
```

I am trying to call the click event on each click. Any help is accepted. I am unable to optimize the code.

Comment: cant access content document across iframe without using postMessage API

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the function outside of the loop and in the loop assign the function:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('contentFrame');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var buttons =innerDoc.getElementsByClassName('RIC_Metrics');
var WTz_linkric_rp;

function onClick() {
    var DCSuri = "/edge/web/public/viewGroupBenefits/RIC";

    if(this.id === "Retirement Income Center")
        WTz_linkric_rp = "TopNav_Retirement Income Centre";
    else(this.id === "Retirement Income Education")
        WTz_linkric_rp = "TopNav_Retirement Income Education";


    var grpId = Bootstrapper.data.extract('groupNumberForPreSignIn', 'cookie');
    if (typeof window.dcsMultiTrack == "function") window.dcsMultiTrack("DCS.dcsuri", DCSuri, "WT.z_linkric_rp_test", WTz_linkric_rp,"WT.z_cookieric_rp_test", grpId);
}

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
}
```